# How should I design a re-usable content like table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, application-design

So I've got a database that holds **articles**, **recipes**, and **comments** in seperate tables, and I'm wanting to allow users to be able to **like** each of these content pieces (articles, recipes, comments).

I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to create a re-usable `likes` table which would look something like this:

```
| content_type | user_id | content_id |
| article      | 1       | 1          |
| article      | 1       | 3          |
| article      | 1       | 4          |
| comment      | 2       | 1          |
| comment      | 3       | 1          |
| recipe       | 2       | 1          |
```

So you'd have:

- `content_type`:

which would represent either **article, recipe, or comment**

- `user_id`:

which represents the user who liked the content

- `content_id`:

this would be the primary key of the content piece (article, comment, recipe).

Is it a good idea to do this? There is the potential for millions of records to be inserted into the one table.

The alternative (which I am using right now) is that I have a table for each of the content types (**articles, comment, recipe**).

The thing is, I might be adding more content types to my database, which means the `likes`  schema I proposed might be a better idea.

Can anyone point out any cons of using a schema like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a good design that you proposed. Just make sure that the table is indexed properly. Consider that every query to the table will probably filter by content_type so that should probably be the leading column in a multi-field index.